# How to arrange them in ascending or descinding order after drop function

Tags: r

```r
library(QCA)
library(dplyr)
ttrows = apply(NF[,1:4],2, function(x) as.numeric(x > 0.5))
rownames(ttrows) = rownames(NF)
drop(ttrows %*% c(8, 4, 2, 1)) + 1

Output:
AU BE DK FR DE IE IT NL NO SE UK US 
14 10 10 13 13  8  6  9 12 12 16 13
```

How to arrange them in descending order?

I need UK to be the first one. Next AU.  Then DE, US and FR and so on.

Comment: What packages are loaded? Where is the drop function from?

Comment: @PKumar Please check the question now.

Comment: @RamakrishnaS I hope this is what you are expecting `v <- drop(ttrows %*% c(8, 4, 2, 1)) + 1;`
`names(v) <- rownames(NF);`
`sort(v, decreasing =TRUE);`